# Validating the current state of a model using DRF?

Tags: django, validation, django-rest-framework

Our application allows users to specify which fields are required for a particular model. This model also has a `status` field. There can be different requirements based on the `status`. For example, `status = foo` and `status = bar` will require a different set of fields to be set.

The challenge is how to validate that these fields have been set. If we simply had to validate that the required fields were set when creating a new instance, we could set `required=True` at runtime. However, because it's based on the `status`, we need to be able to validate an arbitrary model instance against a list of required fields and verify that those fields are set.

As an example, suppose we are patching an existing model instance. Even if we know what the required fields are, patching by design does not support `required=True`. The patch may change a field to be empty, so we need to validate how the model looks after the patch is applied.

One idea is to serialize the model instance, then have a function that takes the serialized `dict` and the list of required fields, and checks each one by hand. This approach is straightforward, but I'd prefer if we could use DRF to handle it so that we can rely on using serializer fields instead of doing it manually.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

I should add that our current approach looks something like this:

```py
instance = SomeModel()
missing = []
required = ["field1", "field2", "field3"]

for f in required:
  if getattr(instance, f, None) in (None, "", {}, []):
    missing.append(f)
```

However, this feels really hacky and I'd prefer to have   validation that is more structured. This approach also doesn't work with checking ManyToManyFields